# Laravel form validation: same as field a or b

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have 3 fields: player1, player2 and winner. I want to validate that winner is equal to either player1 or player 2.

I tried looking for a way to add an 'or' clause to the validation but couldn't find anything, only workarounds for different problems.

Comment: It's easier to compare as usual i think

Comment: `($winner==$player1)||($winner==$player2)` or `in_array($winner, Array($player1, $player2))` - yes, these are definitely the workarounds but what's wrong with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this rule should be registered with extendDependent to correctly resolve parameter names when used with arrays.
Final code:

```php
class OneOfRule
{

    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

        if(is_null($value)) return true;

        foreach($parameters as $param) {
            $other = Arr::get($validator->getData(), $param);
            if ($value === $other) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extendDependent('one_of', 'App\Http\Validation\Rules\OneOfRule@validate');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom validation rule to do this. There's nothing built in that allows comparison to one of many other fields. The closest is the `same` check, but it only checks against one other field.

(I've added `dd()` to dump data, you can remove them)

The `$values` will be what comes from your input.
The `$validationRules` can be adjusted for your needs.

```php
        Validator::extend('equals_one_of', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, \Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validator) {
            $fields = $validator->getData(); // all posted values

            foreach($parameters as $param) { // this is each of the comma separated fields in the validationRules array
                if ($value == $fields[$param]) {
                    dd("matched");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            dd("no match");
            return false;
        });

        $values = [
            'player1' => 'test1',
            'player2' => 'test2',
            'winner' => 'test1'
        ];

        $validationRules = [
            'player1' => 'required',
            'player2' => 'required',
            'winner' => 'required|equals_one_of:player1,player2'
        ];

        $validate = Validator::make($values, $validationRules);
        // use your validator as normal.
        dd($validate->validate());
```